# Import CSV file to List, use file name as identifier

Tags: python, list, csv, pandas

Thank you for helping me clarify my question as well.  Two sets of code below.

First retrieves data from online data source, adds stock symbol as identifier, "AA" in output example below, and creates list with downloaded data, works perfect.

```
stocks = ['AA', 'AAPL', 'IBM']
start = datetime(1990, 1, 1)
end = datetime.today()

data = {}
for stock in stocks:
print stock
stkd = DataReader(stock, 'yahoo', start, end).sort_index()
data[stock] = stkd

Output:  
**{'AA':**     OPEN HIGH LOW CLOSE VOLUME
Date
1990-01-02  75.00  75.62  74.25  75.62   4039200    
1990-01-03  76.00  76.75  76.00  76.75   7332000
```

Second reads CSV files and creates list, just fine, goal is to add identifier(using CSV file name), similar to code above, as data is imported and List is created.

Code for CSV read.

```
path =r'C:\Users\Data'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list = []
for file in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)
    list.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list)

Current Output:

[             Time    Open    High     Low   Close     Vol      OI
 Date                                                             
 12/17/1984  11:15  817.75  820.25  817.00  820.25   73445  309260
 12/18/1984  11:15  820.25  821.00  818.50  819.25   87505  308240

Desired Output:

 {'XX':        Time    Open    High     Low   Close     Vol      OI
 Date                                                             
 12/17/1984  11:15  817.75  820.25  817.00  820.25   73445  309260
 12/18/1984  11:15  820.25  821.00  818.50  819.25   87505  308240
```

Would like read XX.csv, make XX identifier for incoming values and then repeat process with YY.csv, GG.CSV into one combined list or panel.

Have tried several things without much luck, I'm new to python but have gotten along fairly well thanks to Stackoverflow and like sites.

CSV file format

```
Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Vol,OI
12/17/1984,11:15,817.75,820.25,817,820.25,73445,309260
12/18/1984,11:15,820.25,821,818.5,819.25,87505,308240
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing in the first case is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with string keys and DataFrame values. A minimal example:

```
import pandas

data = {}
for key in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    data[key] = pandas.DataFrame({'Column': [1]})
print data
```

Output:

```
{'A':    Column
0       1, 'B':    Column
0       1, 'C':    Column
0       1}
```

In your second case you are using a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists). Just for future reference, you shouldn't use the name `list`, as it shadows the built-in list constructor.

The example I had before can be redone with lists:

```
data = []
for key in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    data.append(pandas.DataFrame({'Column': [1]}))
print data
```

Output:

```
[   Column
0       1,    Column
0       1,    Column
0       1]
```

So, to match your first case, you should use a dictionary for your CSV files rather than a list, something like this:

data = {} # note I've changed list to data, and used {} instead of []
for file in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)
    data[file] = df # Here I've changed the way of adding the data

Answer (score -1):

You could just add the CSV file name after the list has been created.
After the for loop and before you define frame, replace the left bracket ('[') with whatever you want.

So... (note line 4)

```
for file in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0)
    list.append(df)
list[0].replace("[", "**{'XX':**")
frame = pd.concat(list)
```

I'm not saying this is the cleanest way, but it will work. I'm also not sure what you were saying about changing '[' to '{' but that change isn't required (you certainly *can* though).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response.   In example, "XX" is CSV file name (XX.csv), along with several other files, say YY.csv, GG.csv, etc...

Comment: Thank you for your response.   In example, "XX" is CSV file name (XX.csv), along with several other files, say YY.csv, GG.csv, etc...   Would like read XX.csv, make XX identifier for incoming values and then repeat process with YY.csv, GG.CSV into one combined list or panel.  Thank you for helping me clarify my question as well.

Comment: @Benji if you look closely at the code the OP posted, the output is not a string which contains "[" but rather the "[" is displayed when the list is displayed, so this method will not work at all.